# How to execute a Discord command by calling a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, command-line-interface, discord.py

So, I was making a CLI program that allows you to execute commands without having to type anything in a channel. I did some head scratching but failed with all my attempts. What I tried was calling the commands function after `bot.run` but it did not seem to work as it would only execute once the bot has went offline. This is my code:

```
def main():
    global guildid
    print(f"{Fore.BLUE}Enter your bots token{Fore.WHITE}: ")
    token = input()
    login(token)

def login(token):
    bot.run(token,bot=False)

async def myCommand(ctx):
    print("noice")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you can post answers to your own questions. If you figured it out yourself, you can post the solution as an answer

Comment: @ForceBru LMAO I did not know that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and for anyone browsing this thread, you can simply do this:
make an on_ready() function, its executed as soon as the bot starts. Replace your code with this:

````
def main():
    global guildid
    print(f"{Fore.BLUE}Enter your bots token{Fore.WHITE}: ")
    token = input()
    login(token)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await myCommand()

def login(token):
    bot.run(token,bot=False)

async def myCommand(ctx):
    print("noice")```
````